# Android studio toast message not showing from json

Tags: php, android-studio, android-toast

I am developing an android project and I got a problem:  The toast message is not showing on my application. When I test it on my phone, the toast message gets blank on toast.

here is the Register.java

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText etUsername, etPassword, etPassword2, etEmail;
private Button bRegis;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    etPassword2= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword2);
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    bRegis = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegis);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    bRegis.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void RegisterUser(){
    final String Email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String Username = etUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    final String Password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering User...");
    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Constants.URL_REGISTER,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.hide();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("Username", Username);
            params.put("Email", Email);
            params.put("Password", Password);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestHandler.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view){
    String Password = etPassword.getText().toString();
    String Password2= etPassword2.getText().toString();
    if(Password2.equals(Password) && view == bRegis) {
        RegisterUser();
    }else{
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Error");
        builder.setMessage("Password does not match");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", null);
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
    }

}
}
```

and here is the register.php file

```
<?php
require_once 'DbOperations.php';

$response = array(); 

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
if(
    isset($_POST['Username']) and
        isset($_POST['Email']) and
            isset($_POST['Password']))
    {
    //operate the data further 

    $db = new DbOperations(); 

    $result = $db->createUser(   $_POST['Username'],
                                $_POST['Password'],
                                $_POST['Email']
                            );
    if($result == 1){
        $response["error"] = false; 
        $response["message"] = "User registered successfully";
    }elseif($result == 2){
        $response["error"] = true; 
        $response["message"] = "Some error occurred please try again";          
    }elseif($result == 0){
        $response["error"] = true; 
        $response["message"] = "It seems you are already registered, please choose a different email and username";                     
    }

}else{
    $response['error'] = true; 
    $response['message'] = "Required fields are missing";
}
}else{
$response['error'] = true; 
$response['message'] = "Invalid Request";
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

here is the DbOperations.php

```
<?php 

class DbOperations{

    private $con; 

    function __construct(){

        require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';

        $db = new DbConnect();

        $this->con = $db->connect();

    }

    /*CRUD -> C -> CREATE */

    public function createUser($Username, $Password, $Email){
        if($this->isUserExist($Username,$Email)){
            return 0; 
        }else{
            $Password = md5($Password);
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `User` (`id`, `Username`, `Password`, `Email`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?);");
            $stmt->bind_param("sss",$Username,$Password,$Email);

            if($stmt->execute()){
                return 1; 
            }else{
                return 2; 
            }
        }
    }

    public function UserLogin($Username, $pass){
        $Password = md5($pass);
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM User WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$Username,$Password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0; 
    }

    public function getUserByUsername($Username){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM User WHERE Username = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$Username);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    }


    private function isUserExist($Username, $Email){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM User WHERE Username = ? OR Email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $Username, $Email);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0; 
    }

}
?>
```

here the image of my problem:

[toast message blank on phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBAIx.jpg)

Thanks in advance, sorry for my bad English

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using MD5() or SHA1(). PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: you can try to log the response variable to see what it contains

Comment: @RiggsFolly ah i see, thanks i will try to use it, but my real problem is the toast message

Comment: @gratienasimbahwe where to see the log ? sry really new in android studio

Comment: No matter. inside `public void onResponse(String response) {` insert `Log.d("RESPONSE",response)` and at runtime, if your device is connected to android studio, locate **logcat** at the bottom of android studio and open it. Then in the search field insert "RESPONSE" as key

Comment: check your API response using POSTMAN or use this link to check your response first: https://www.codepunker.com/tools/http-requests . Do provide your API URL so that we can check.

Comment: @gratienasimbahwethis is the log ? **D/RESPONSE: a{"error":true,"message":"It seems you are already registered, please choose a different email and username"}**

Comment: here is my API URL @ShubhamAgrawal http://justassasin.000webhostapp.com/connect/RegisterUser.php , i have tried it on my own but don't know how to use POSTMAN nor codepunker

Comment: @Delalune Is that a direct copy/paste of the log output? If it is, then it looks like possibly somehow your server is echoing an "a" in front of the JSON, which would make it invalid.

Comment: There is no problem in your android code, the problem is with your PHP code since it sending `a{}` before your response

Comment: yes it is direct copy paste from the log output @zenzelezz

Comment: yeah i wonder about where the `a{}` come from @ShubhamAgrawal

Answer (score 0):

Here is my simple Api.php file. Hope this helps:

```
<?php  
    require_once 'DbConnect.php';

    $response = array();

    if(isset($_GET['apicall'])){

        switch($_GET['apicall']){

            case 'add_data':
                if(isTheseParametersAvailable(array('name','email', 'phone'))){
                    $name = $_POST['name']; 
                    $phone = $_POST['phone']; 
                    $email = $_POST['email'];

                    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO users(name, email, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
                    $stmt->bind_param("sss", $name, $email, $phone);

                    if($stmt->execute()){
                        $stmt->close();
                        $response['error'] = false; 
                        $response['message'] = 'Data entered successfully'; 
                    }else{
                        $response['error'] = true; 
                        $response['message'] = 'Cannot enter data';
                    } 
                }else{
                    $response['error'] = true; 
                    $response['message'] = 'required parameters are not available'; 
                }
            break;



            default: 
            $response['error'] = true; 
            $response['message'] = 'Invalid Operation Called';
        }

    }else{
        $response['error'] = true; 
        $response['message'] = 'Invalid API Call';
    }

 echo json_encode($response);

 function isTheseParametersAvailable($params){

    foreach($params as $param){
        if(!isset($_POST[$param])){
        return false; 
    }
 }
 return true; 
 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After your final variables, define bellow variable too:

```
final Activity currentActivity = this;
```

Now, use of this variable instead of `getApplicationContext()` in Toast:

```
Toast.makeText(currentActivity, jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Or

```
Toast.makeText(currentActivity, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Sorry ... I just checked the java Code.